# Incorrect align of Table with scroll-bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is like below,

[image]

I have to use scroll-bar partially in the table, so I think how I can do it.

My conclusion is just use **THREE** tables and locate these appropriately.

The first table is upper one, has full width. The second one is under, left table which have scroll bar and yellow background.

The Third one is last one, skyblue+blue one.

The problem is, as you can see, the alignment is incorrect. 
the pink background and skyblue background is not matched vertically.

Further more, in IE, the Third table located in under Second table, not horizontally aligned.

I made a fiddle. (https://jsfiddle.net/bexoss/ru2b9gmq/1/)

```
// Please see the fiddle, that has below code 

// save each of table1's td width
var tds = [$('.td1').width(), $('.td2').width(), $('.td3').width(), $('.td4').width(), $('.td5').width() ];

// set table2-wrapper's width to tds[0] + tds[1], and make it scrollable
$('.table2-wrapper').css({'display' : 'inline-block', 'width' : Number(tds[0] + tds[1]),'height': $('#table1').height(), 'overflow-y': 'scroll','padding' : 0, 'margin' : 0 });

// set table3-wrapper's width to tds[2]+tds[3]+tds[4] 
$('.table3-wrapper').css({'display' : 'inline-block', 'width' : Number(tds[2] + tds[3] + tds[4] ),'height': $('#table1').height(),'padding' : 0, 'margin' : 0 });

// set table3's first row's width to same with table1's red row 
$('.table3-td1').css('width', tds[2]);
```

How can I make it to correctly aligned smartly or any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

Just use 1 table ( position: relative; ),

and another table ( position: absolute; bottom:0; left:0; )

It solves problem.